# How do I reset TimeMachine to remove backup history if the backup volume is no longer available?

Tags: macos, time-machine

My virus application found a virus in the backup. I formatted the backup volume, so the backup no longer exists. However it still exists in Time Machine's history. `tmutil delete` fails because it can't find the backup. I need to clear the Time Machine history. How can I achieve this?

Comment: a) You could have just deleted the virus; if it exists in the backup but not on disk it was never going to be any harm [& likely either a Win virus or false positive anyway] b) just remove the drive from the Time Machine control panel, the snapshots will clean themselves up.

Answer (score 1):

First list the local snapshots:

`sudo tmutil listlocalsnapshots`

This will output (for example):

```
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-06-05-112020
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-06-05-122034
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-06-05-135447
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-06-05-201511
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-06-05-224434
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-06-06-000729
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-06-06-010257
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-06-06-043819
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-06-06-081034
com.apple.TimeMachine.2019-06-06-095111
```

Then delete them one by one by date:

`sudo tmutil deletelocalsnapshots 2019-06-05-122034`